# Slideshow not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn how to implement a slideshow into my website. I want to just have the one at w3schools for now: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots2
But when I use any of their tutorials, I end up with the buttons below the image and bugs everywhere. I copy pasted their entire code into my editor, and got the same result, so there wasn't a misunderstanding. I haven't found any other tutorials that explain what I want to have, I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with their code.

Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Slideshow Indicators</h2>
  <p>An example of using buttons to indicate how many slides there are in the slideshow, and which slide the user is currently viewing.</p>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-padding-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-padding-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's in `/lib/w3.css`? Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Try to remove `/lib/w3.css` from w3 editor, i'm sure you will get buttons below of images. You just need to copy content from that file.